# jdbc over tcp/ip much slower than on local machine

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, tcp, jboss

we have a three tier Java application with Jboss as application server an MS Sql Server as db server. We connect from App server to Db server using jdbc type 4.

We have seen that running Jboss and DB server on the same machine result in a performance gain of ~50% in respect if they are on separate machines. How to explain such a big difference?
The machines on which Jboss and DB Server run are really good workstations (with the best intel CPU available) and the network is 1Gb Ethernet with business standard infrastructure.

You think it is a problem on our network (latency, throughput,...) or there are some other reasons that could explain the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The following factors could potentially affect the performance in the above case,

1) *Network latency in accessing DB*: In local machine, it would be less than 1 ms. If the DB server & app server is located on different locations, the latency would be more. If you make "n" DB calls for serving a particular request, the delay would be n * 2 * latency.

Solution: Make fewer calls. Use caching for reference dataset.

2) *Location of accessing the app server*: If the user is located in US & the appserver is in India then the network latency would be around 200ms. If many css & js files are loaded on the page, it would cause a lot of delay depending on the browser used.

Solution: Combile all js files into one file. Use GZip for js & css. Minify JS. Use browser cache effectively.

3) *If the above two are not the bottlenecks, check the CPU, memory & disk speed on the server where the application is deployed.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are too much possibilities:
1) Network settings
2) Firewalls
3) Implementation of the communication services
4) etc.

I suggest to disable all the services, options, filters and then try to enable one by one.
If this doesn't work, then check your code.

Good luck, it is not easy!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your configuration, SQL Server uses named pipes by default as transport. Locally, this would be an in-memory intra-process communication which is faster than TCP/IP. If remote, the pipe would need to be transported over TCP/IP, which adds it's own overhead in marshaling/unmarshaling up and down the TCP/IP stack (as well as the actual transmission).

You say you use TCP, but it could be that you are actually using named pipes locally. What does your connection string look like?